# Python equivalent for Matlab corrcoef (correlation coefficient )

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Matlab has a function for calculating correlation coefficient that returns the correlation coefficient matrix [R] and the P-matrix (matrix of p-values for testing the hypothesis of no correlation)

So, if my data looked like so,

```
X =

   14.2000  215.0000   -1.5771
   16.4000  325.0000    0.5080
   11.9000  185.0000    0.2820
   15.2000  332.0000    0.0335
   18.5000  406.0000   -1.3337
   22.1000  522.0000    1.1275
   10.4000  412.0000    0.3502
   25.1000  614.0000   -0.2991
   23.4000  544.0000    0.0229
   18.1000  421.0000   -0.2620
   22.6000  445.0000   -1.7502
   17.2000  408.0000   -0.2857
```

I could do,

```
>> [r,p] = corrcoef(X)

r =

    1.0000    0.8120   -0.1209
    0.8120    1.0000    0.1521
   -0.1209    0.1521    1.0000


p =

    1.0000    0.0013    0.7082
    0.0013    1.0000    0.6369
    0.7082    0.6369    1.0000
```

When looking at the p-matrix, I can conclude that the probablity of no-correlation between column1 and column2 is 0.13% and the probability of no-correlation between column1 and column2 is 70%.

I am trying find the same function in python. numpy/pandas offers the corr() function. But this only return the R-matrix and not the P-matrix

Is there are python equivalent function for matlab's corrcoef ?

Comment: numpy.corrcoef seems to return the P matrix ?

Comment: I am looking for a python function that return P-matrix... is there one?

Comment: Seems like you will have to compute it by yourself and it is not that difficult

Comment: I don't know of any Python native functions that will do that for you.  Best bet is to either implement it yourself, or use `numpy`.